# spring mvc not initialized

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I need to convert old spring xml application to java config no web.xml.

I add this class:

```
public class WebServletConfiguration implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(SpringConfiguration.class);

        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.register(SpringConfiguration.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}



@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "{com.ciro}")
public class SpringConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/static/")
                .setCachePeriod(365 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(handlerTimeLongInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**")
                .excludePathPatterns("/secure/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        registry.jsp("/WEB-INF/view/", ".jsp");
    }

.....



}
```

but controller is not mapped and all request return 404. With xml configuration all works fine. What I missing?

Comment: Please confirm if the controllers are annotated and the component-scan scans the package ?

Comment: Also [AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.register()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.html#register-java.lang.Class...-) should follow a `refresh()` in order for the context to fully process the new classes . I think that should fix the issue here

Answer (score 0):

I modified the method in this way and it works

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(SpringConfiguration.class);
    rootContext.scan("com.ciro");
    container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");
}
```